# Matching matrix rows with list elements in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, conditional-statements, apply

A reproducible data:

```
dat1 <- matrix(0, nrow = 9, ncol = 2)
dat1[,1] <- rep(1:3,3)
dat1[,2] <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)

dat2 <- list()
dat2[[1]] <- matrix(c(1,2,1,3), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
dat2[[2]] <- matrix(c(1,1,2,3,1,3), nrow = 3, ncol = 2 )

> dat1
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2    1
 [3,]    3    1
 [4,]    1    2
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    3    2
 [7,]    1    3
 [8,]    2    3
 [9,]    3    3

> dat2
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    3

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    2    3
```

I have a matrix (dat1) and a list (dat2).

Some rows of dat1 is same as some of the list elements of dat2. My objective is to find out the corresponding row numbers of dat1 that are matched with dat2 and store them in a list. AN EXAMPLE of the output:

```
> ex.result
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    8

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]    1
[3,]    8
```

I am looking for a fast way to do this without using time consuming loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different approach:

```r
lapply( dat2, function(m) {
    apply( m, 1, function(r) 
        which( apply( sweep( dat1, 2, r, "=="  ), 1, all ) ) ) %>% as.matrix })
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    8

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]    1
[3,]    8
```

Comment: I like this solution but the problem is that it's not generic. dat1 is not limited to only 2 columns and therefore I can not use it dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option:

```r
lapply(dat2, function(mat) 
    apply(mat, 1, function(row) 
        match(toString(row), apply(dat1, 1, toString))))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 8
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 7 1 8
```

This returns a `list` with integer vectors instead of a `list` with `array`/`matrix` entries though.

Comment: Will it be difficult to return with array/matrix? For my purpose, I find it a bit difficult to use with vector output.

Comment: @Rel_Ai You can always do `as.matrix` to force a `matrix` output. Having said that, a vector of indices seems more natural (to me) than a single column `matrix`. If your objects are small, then I would recommend working with `list`s and vectors (rather than `matrix` and `array` objects. But obviously I don't know the bigger picture that motivated your question, so this is just my subjective view.

Answer (score 1):

In the same vein as above, using `Map()` and vector recycling:

```
# Coercing to a data.frame to recycle the vector that is used to search: 
setNames(
  Map(function(x, y){
    matrix(
      match(
        apply(y, 1, paste, collapse = ", "),
        x
      )
    )
  }, 
  data.frame(apply(dat1, 1, paste, collapse = ", ")),
  dat2), 
seq_len(length(dat2)))
```

Comment: This one does what it's supposed to but it looks a bit complicated to me. I will give myself a bit more time to understand.

Comment: No worries, it is essentially the same as the other solutions.